# Regex to remove " ' and space from column

Tags: sql-server, patindex

I need to select column from a table removing " ' and space and that is to be exported in a csv file. for example if the column contain *"155/229-230 Moo 10 , Nuanchan Road"* I shall have to remove the leading and ending quotes to *155/229-230 Moo 10 , Nuanchan Road*

I was trying

```
SELECT '"SQL Server String Function"'
    , substring('"SQL Server String Function"', patindex('%[^"'' ]%','"SQL Server String Function"'), LEN('"SQL Server String Function"')) position;
```

but it is not removing the ending quotes.

Comment: Why do the spaces in your example remain?

Comment: Can you just do a `replace()` for the quote characters?

Comment: I'm not understanding why you need to remove spaces, quotes and apostrophes. Correct CSV encoding can handle spaces, commas, quotes and even linebreaks in field data as per [RFC 4180 Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180).

Comment: Your sample above contains a comma.  If you remove the quotes, this value will actually be two columns when output to a csv.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL 2017 [`TRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) was introduced.

Your code would look like this:

```
SELECT TRIM( '"'' ' FROM  '"SQL Server String Function"') AS Result
```

**Note:** I don't have access to SQL 2017 to give you a working sample.

For earlier versions it is a little more complicated (credit goes to [Randi Vertongen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/233347/94130)):

```
DECLARE @pat VARCHAR( 10 )= '%[^''" ]%'
DECLARE @strTbl TABLE( string VARCHAR( 40 ))
INSERT INTO @strTbl VALUES
( '''" SQL Server "String Function "''' ),
( '''" SQL Server "String Function' ),
( 'SQL Server "String Function' ),
( 'SQL Server "String Functio''n' );

SELECT RIGHT( string, LEN( string ) - PATINDEX( @pat, string ) + 1 ) -- Remove leading
FROM
    ( SELECT LEFT( string, LEN( string ) - PATINDEX( @pat, REVERSE( string )) + 1 ) AS string -- Remove trailing
    FROM @strTbl ) AS a;
```

How it works:

- `'%[^''" ]%'` - is looking for the first **non**-excluded character in string
- `PATINDEX( @pat, REVERSE( string ))` - finds the **last** non-excluded character

### Limitations

Due to [`LEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) function not counting trailing spaces, this logic will work correctly if you want to keep trailing spaces.